# Balls and Bins probability

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds, balls-in-bins

Consider a balls-and-bins game with m balls and n bins. Each ball is independently thrown into a bin that is chosen uniformly at random.

Question: Show that, for some $k$, the probability that at least one bin gets more than $k$ balls is bounded by
$$\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^k\frac{n}{k!}$$

Approach:

I already know that if $E_i$ is the event that the $i$ th bin contains more than or equal to $k$ balls, then
$$
p\left(E_i\right) \leq\begin{array}{c}
m \choose k
\end{array}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k
$$
and then we take union bound over all bins and by Stirling's approximation, the total probability is bounded on the above by
$$\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^k \frac{n}{k !} $$
But here in the question we have strictly more than $k$ balls and yet they ask to prove the same bound. So I am wondering if there is something wrong with the question or can my solution be modified slightly to prove the required claim.

Comment: A generally useful probability trick is whenever you need to calculate the probability that "at least one ...", instead calculate the probability that "no ...." as these two events are complementary: one will ocurr if and only if the other does not. Thus their probabilities sum to $1$. And usually the no case is much easier to calculate.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That seems like terrible advice in the context of this problem.